# IP with JSON file

Tags: php, location, ip, php-7

guys. I have written a small piece of code to get the IP of the visitor of the site, so I want to ask you where should I put `$ip` to get the current location.

```
<?php
     $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
     $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://freegeoip.net/json/{$ip}/github.com"));
     echo $details->city;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `"https://freegeoip.net/json/{$ip}"` as URL. The `github.com` is probably taken from the example on https://freegeoip.net that you can also query with a hostname instead of an IP address.